# i am looping through each cell in excel using vba i want to print certain values only if the address is in column 5 any row

Tags: excel, vba

> i am looping through each cell in excel using vba i want to print certain values only if the address is in column 5 any row.
> 'i want to execute after "erow" only if selCell.address belongs to column  5 any row.

For Each selCell In dataRng

```
    If selCell.Value <> Worksheets(3).Range(selCell.Address).Value Then
```

'i want to execute this below lines only if selCell.address belongs to column  5 any row.

```
        erow = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
         
        ' this will print the issue id which is not equal to the previous sheet, issue key, current and prev status.
        
        Worksheets(4).Range(selCell.Address).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        
        Worksheets(2).Cells(erow, 1) = Worksheets(4).Range(selCell.Address).Offset(, -2)
        Worksheets(2).Cells(erow, 2) = Worksheets(4).Range(selCell.Address).Offset(, -3)
        Worksheets(2).Cells(erow, 3) = Worksheets(4).Range(selCell.Address).Value
        Worksheets(2).Cells(erow, 4) = Worksheets(3).Range(selCell.Address).Value
        'Worksheets(2).Cells(erow, 5) = Worksheets(3).Range(selCell.Address).Value
        sSheetName = "current_sheet"
        'Worksheets("changes_sheet").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=changes_sheet.Cells(erow, 5), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & "'!" & Target.Address, TextToDisplay:=Target.Address
        Worksheets(2).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets(2).Cells(erow, 5), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & sSheetName & "'!" & selCell.Address, TextToDisplay:=selCell.Address
```

````
``` i tried to use if and else. couldnt do it pls help

    For Each selCell In dataRng
    
        If selCell.Value <> Worksheets(3).Range(selCell.Address).Value Then
        
            'if selCell.Address =
            
            'If Not Application.Intersect(selCell, Range("e1:e10000")) Is Nothing Then
            'MsgBox selCell.Address
            
            
            erow = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
             
            ' this will print the issue id which is not equal to the previous sheet, issue key, current and prev status.
            
            Worksheets(4).Range(selCell.Address).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            
            Worksheets(2).Cells(erow, 1) = Worksheets(4).Range(selCell.Address).Offset(, -2)
            Worksheets(2).Cells(erow, 2) = Worksheets(4).Range(selCell.Address).Offset(, -3)
            Worksheets(2).Cells(erow, 3) = Worksheets(4).Range(selCell.Address).Value
            Worksheets(2).Cells(erow, 4) = Worksheets(3).Range(selCell.Address).Value
            'Worksheets(2).Cells(erow, 5) = Worksheets(3).Range(selCell.Address).Value
            sSheetName = "current_sheet"
            'Worksheets("changes_sheet").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=changes_sheet.Cells(erow, 5), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & "'!" & Target.Address, TextToDisplay:=Target.Address
            Worksheets(2).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets(2).Cells(erow, 5), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & sSheetName & "'!" & selCell.Address, TextToDisplay:=selCell.Address
            
            
'            Else
'
'             erow_col = Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
'
'             Worksheets(4).Range(selCell.Address).Interior.Color = vbYellow
'
'            Worksheets(2).Cells(erow_col, 9) = Worksheets(4).Range(selCell.Address).Value
'            Worksheets(2).Cells(erow_col, 10) = Worksheets(3).Range(selCell.Address).Value
'            sSheetName = "current_sheet"
'            Worksheets(2).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets(2).Cells(erow_col, 11), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & sSheetName & "'!" & selCell.Address, TextToDisplay:=selCell.Address
'
'            End If
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to adapt this to your own code ...

```
For Each selCell In Sheet1.Cells
    If selCell.Column = 5 Then
    
    End If
Next
```